# Where do I put an NLog config file if the NLog code is in a NuGet package?

Tags: nuget, .net-6.0, nuget-package, nlog

I'm using Visual Studio 2022, .NET 6.0, C#.  A co-worker has created a NuGet library that is a helper function for NLog.  It creates the logger object and calls the Log method.  What I can't figure out is where to put the NLog.config file.  Where do you put the NLog file in a situation like this?

Here's how the reference to the library is set up in the Test App:
[image]

Here's how it's called in the Test App:

```
// Test App
logger.Log(LogLevel.Debug, message, args);
```

I've tried putting the NLog.config file in these places:

- C:\Test\
- C:\Test\Debug
- C:\Test\Debug\net6.0

Here's my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
  autoReload="true"
  throwExceptions="false"
  internalLogLevel="Off" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log">

  <!-- optional, add some variables
  https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#variables
  -->
  <variable name="myvar" value="myvalue"/>

 <!--
  See https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file
  for information on customizing logging rules and outputs.
   -->
<targets>

    <target xsi:type="File" name="f" fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.log" layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" />
</targets>
<rules>

<!-- Write all events with minimal level of Debug (So Debug, Info, Warn, Error and Fatal, but not Trace)  to "f" -->
<logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="f" />

</rules>
</nlog>
```

I've also tried adding it to appsettings.json.

Here's my appsettings.json code:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "TheSQLConnectionString": ""
  },
  "NLog": {
    "targets": {
      "console": {
        "type": "File",
        "name": "f",
        "fileName": "nlogtest.log"
      }
    },
    "rules": [
      {
        "logger": "*",
        "minLevel": "Trace",
        "writeTo": "f"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here's how the NuGet Library is set up:

```
// NuGet Library
public class NLogHelper : Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger
{
    ...
    public void Log<TState>(
    LogLevel logLevel,
    EventId eventId,
    TState state,
    Exception exception,
    Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
    {
        if (!IsEnabled(logLevel))
        {
            return;
        }

        var nlog = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        switch (logLevel)
        {
            case LogLevel.Trace:
                nlog.Log(NLog.LogLevel.Trace, exception, $"{formatter(state, exception)}");
                break;
            case LogLevel.Debug:
                nlog.Log(NLog.LogLevel.Debug, exception, $"{formatter(state, exception)}");
                break;
            case LogLevel.Information:
                nlog.Log(NLog.LogLevel.Info, exception, $"{formatter(state, exception)}");
                break;
            case LogLevel.Warning:
                nlog.Log(NLog.LogLevel.Warn, exception, $"{formatter(state, exception)}");
                break;
            case LogLevel.Error:
                nlog.Log(NLog.LogLevel.Error, exception, $"{formatter(state, exception)}");
                break;
            case LogLevel.Critical:
                nlog.Log(NLog.LogLevel.Fatal, exception, $"{formatter(state, exception)}");
                break;
        }
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Think the `NLogHelper` from your custom Nuget-Library should be replaced with NLogLoggerFactory from [NLog.Extensions.Logging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Extensions.Logging).

Then at program startup then you should register NLog as Logging-Provider using `AddNLog`:

```
    using NLog.Extensions.Logging;

    private static void Main()
    {
        var logger = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => builder.AddNLog()).CreateLogger("Hello");
        logger.LogInformation("Program has started.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

If having registered NLog as LoggingProvider using `AddNLog` with the [Microsoft HostBuilder](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/blob/master/examples/NetCore2/HostingExample/Program.cs), then NLog will automatically load its configuration from appsettings.json (Retrieved from HostBuilder-Configuration). See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-configuration-with-appsettings.json (Ex. can also load appsettings.json manually with `ConfigurationBuilder`)

NLog will automatically load its configuration from `NLog.config`, if you add the xml-file to your host-application-project, with file-properties `Copy If newer`. See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial

Instead of having NLog-configuration in external files, then you can also [configure NLog from code](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Fluent-Configuration-API):

```cs
NLog.LogManager.Setup().LoadConfiguration(builder => {
   builder.ForLogger().WriteToConsole()
});
```

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I don't think this helps in my case, because I'm not supposed to put any NLog references in the main program only the custom library reference.  Is there anyway to use the custom library and still have it read from appsettings.json or NLog.confiig in the main program?

Comment: @boilers222 You asked how to configure NLog, and I have shown some of the official ways. If your question is how to use custom wrapper developed by some other team. Then I suggest you contact that team, instead of using StackOverflow :)